# ngx-bootstrap - Accordion group within Child Component

Tags: html, angular, bootstrap-4, ng-bootstrap, ngx-bootstrap

**Parent Component**

```
<input type="button" class="btn btn-primary"  (click)="allExpanded = !allExpanded" [attr.value]="allExpanded ? 'Collapse All': 'Expand All'" >  
            <div class="all-components" >
                <accordion>
                    <accordion-group heading="Test1" [isOpen]="allExpanded">
                    Hey
                    </accordion-group>
                    <accordion-group heading="Test2" [isOpen]="allExpanded">
                    Hey
                    </accordion-group>
                    <app-child-comp-1 allExpanded = "{{ allExpanded }}" ></app-child-comp-1>
                    <app-child-comp-2 allExpanded = "{{ allExpanded }}" ></app-child-comp-2>
                </accordion>
            </div>
```

**Child Component 1**

```
<accordion-group heading="Child Component *ngIf="dataExists" [isOpen]="allExpanded">
Hey
</accordion-group>
```

**What I'm trying to do**

Maintain the accordion in the Parent Component and call the Child Components which have the <accordion-group>

When clicking the button in Parent Component set <accordion-group> [isOpen] attributes to true/false as a way of collapsing/expanding all components

**Why I'm trying to do it this way**

Certain child components may not have data and if that is the case I don't want the <accordion-group> to be displayed

For example:

```
<accordion-group heading="Child Component" *ngIf="dataExists" [isOpen]="allExpanded">
Hey
</accordion-group>
```

If Child Component 1's dataExists is false don't display this <accordion-group>

**Issues I'm Facing**

Passing in allExpanded to the Child Components and setting [isOpen]="allExpanded" is not working as expected within the child components - It only expands, it does not collapse.

It does work for the <accordion-group>'s that were defined in the Parent Component. It seems to me that the issue is related to how Child Components are called from Parent Components but I'm very new to Angular so I am lost.

**Observations**

When clicking the Expand/Collapse button, all [isOpen]'s change from True to False, but the class for the groups only changes for those defined in the parent, not those defined in the child components.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seems like you need a child component here. `ng-container` would be enough

```
<input type="button" class="btn btn-primary"  (click)="allExpanded = !allExpanded" [attr.value]="allExpanded ? 'Collapse All': 'Expand All'" >  
            <div class="all-components" >
                <accordion>
                    <accordion-group heading="Test1" [isOpen]="allExpanded">
                    Hey
                    </accordion-group>
                    <accordion-group heading="Test2" [isOpen]="allExpanded">
                    Hey
                    </accordion-group>
                    <ng-container *ngIf="dataExists">
                       <accordion-group heading="Child Component" [isOpen]="allExpanded">
                          Hey
                       </accordion-group>
                       <accordion-group heading="Child Component" [isOpen]="allExpanded">
                          Hey
                       </accordion-group>
                    </ng-container>
                </accordion>
            </div>
```